# PHP array logic

Tags: php, mysql

How can I set up an array of subjects with boolean values or test scores stored in them?

I am trying to display a gold medal if someone makes high scores on every test in a subject.

I wish I could be more clear in the framing of this question, but here is some code to help elucidate:

```
$resTestsQryStr = "SELECT TestID, Subject FROM Tests
                            WHERE " . $edstr . " AND " . $plstr . " AND " . $levelStr . " GROUP BY Subject";
$resTests = mysql_query($resTestsQryStr);

while ($rowT=mysql_fetch_array($resTests))
{
    $subject=$rowT['Subject'];    
    $tID=$rowT['TestID'];
    $resScore= mysql_query("SELECT Score FROM CompletedTests WHERE UserNum = '$userNum' AND TestID = '$tID'");
    $rowScore= mysql_fetch_array($resScore);      
        if ($rowScore['Score'] < 100){
            $medalWinArray[$subject]= false;
            break;
        }
        else    
            $medalWinArray[$subject]= true;
}
```

Comment: You should seriously consider using a JOIN between your two tables.

Comment: Also, why doesn't the current code work? How should it work?

Comment: And don't use arrays to manipulate sets of data retrieved from a database - manipulate the data IN THE DATABASE then use an array to store the results.

Comment: Why do you have `GROUP BY Subject` in the first query? That means you'll just get one `TestID` for each subject, instead of every test they took.

Comment: PHP functions that start with mysql_ have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the MySQLi or PDO extensions instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT Subject, MIN(Score) >= 100 GoldMedal
FROM Tests t
JOIN Completed Tests c ON c.TestID = t.TestID
WHERE $edstr AND $plstr AND $level
AND c.userNum = '$userNum'
GROUP BY Subject
```